# What is the reason ESlint doesn't work in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

ESlint does not hook the code and does not give errors when saving, but if you run the ***npm run lint*** command, then the errors are shown, I will attach screenshots with the settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.1",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
```

Comment: Please create issue in [vscode_github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) or just simply reinstall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this steps:

1. Install eslint extention on vscode
2. From vscode settings, formatting section, uncheck Format on save
3. Add settings to .vscode folder

> Depending on which features/presets you are using, you can add the related options to .vscode/settings.json

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.fixAll.eslint"
  ],
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "vue"]
}
```

4. Close and re-open vscode